# How to set active navigation item with javascript only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar with a nested menu inside. That menu hosts links. I want the currently selected menu item to have the CSS class `active`. How do I do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/1wjba46j/

My js looks like this:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$('.nav-side-menu ul li a').each(function () {
    var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
    // $(this).toggleClass('active', status);
    if (status) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to set your active class after page reload?

Comment: yes sir, can you help me? :( @cl3m

Comment: You need either to do it server side with a variable you will pass to the view, or you need to pass the clicked element index, or hierarchy information via the url query string. You then extract that information on page load and set the class accordingly. It also depends if you are using a Single Page Application as well.

Comment: i dont understand about that, im so sorry sir. can i get the alternative with jquery? @cl3m

Comment: If you want to do it all in jQuery you'll need a mapping between urls and menu elements. Then get the `window.location.href` and set the corresponding element to `active` after page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plain js solution.

```
// put your mapping here
var mapping = {
    "http://example.org/page1": "css.path.to.your.element",
    "http://example.org/page2": "path.to.other.element",
}

$(function(){
    $(mapping[window.location.href]).addClass('active');
});
```

It's nothing more but a simple mapping between your page URLs and the nav elements (their CSS path).

Also you will probably want to expand the menu if an item within that (sub-) menu is active. So you will want to add something like this:

```
$(mapping[window.location.href]).parent("ul").prev("li").addClass("active").click()
```

Add error checks where needed.